# If I do "jquery sortable" on a contenteditable item(s), I then can't focus mouse anywhere inside contenteditable text anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, contenteditable

Strangely this is broken only in Firefox and Opera (IE, Chrome and Safari works as it should).

Any suggestions for a quick fix?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js&quot; type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js&quot; type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sortable').sortable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="sortable">
    <p contenteditable="true">One apple</p>
    <p>Two pears</p>
    <p>Three oranges</p>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 39):

I have found another "solution" to this problem.

When declaring your sortable, you should add a cancel: option like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sortable').sortable({cancel: ':input,button,.contenteditable'});
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="sortable">
    <p contenteditable="true" class="contenteditable">One apple</p>
    <p>Two pears</p>
    <p>Three oranges</p>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

This version does not force your cursor at the start, but you also can't drag using this field. I'd advice wrapping the `<p>` in a container which has some sort of dragging handle (like the dots at the start of every row in gmail).

side remark: `':input,button'` is required, because that is the default option. If you do not add these, you get similar problems with inputfields and buttons.

Comment: Just want to add that instead of doing
`$('#sortable').sortable({cancel: ':input,button,.contenteditable'});`,

you can do
`$('#sortable').sortable({cancel: ':input,button,[contenteditable]'});`.

Then you don't need to add the .contenteditable class to the elements at all.

Comment: In my case just `cancel: [contenteditable]` was sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

Yes so for me it was the combination of adding:

```
cancel: 'input,textarea,button,select,option,[contenteditable]'
```

and then taking off the `.disableSelection();`

so i'm left with:

```
$("#sortable_list").sortable({
    cancel: 'input,textarea,button,select,option,[contenteditable]'
});
```

Comment: hi , in my case the text is select and focus but can not change , but without select text I can add and remove text !

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe its removing 'disableSelection' that does the trick. Turns out you shouldn't use it (despite it appearing in the jQuery UI sortable demo code). https://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it was because I was using the function `disableSelection()` together `sortable()`

Comment: Yes! And since all jQueryUI tutorials tell you to use it, why wouldn't you? Until it causes these kinds of problems :-)

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is working, as you can see by pressing tab: the editable element receives focus. I think the problem is that the sortable plug-in is hijacking the `mousedown` event and thus preventing the editable element from receiving focus when you click on it.

A workaround is to add a `mousedown` event handler to the editable element that ensures it receives focus:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sortable').sortable();
      $('#editable')[0].onmousedown = function() {
          this.focus();
      };
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="sortable">
    <p contenteditable="true" id="editable">One apple</p>
    <p>Two pears</p>
    <p>Three oranges</p>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim!
contenteditable element now receives focus, but I then still can't change focus by clicking mouse anywhere inside "One apple" text.
I guess focus() trigger always puts cursor at the start of contenteditable element's text.

Comment: Good point. Short of amending the sortable plug-in code, I'm struggling to think of a good way round this.

Answer (score 3):

specify a classname for all editable content, then capture all the onmousedown events using this:

```
$('.classname').each ( function(){
    $(this)[0].onmousedown = function() {
        this.focus();
    };
});
```

Comment: you should be able to simply do `$('.classname').onmousedown = function () { this.focus(); };`

Answer (score 2):

The Patrigan answer is correct, but there's a slightly better way to specify the cancel, such as:

```
{cancel: 'input,textarea,button,select,option,[contenteditable]'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but it actually happened due to "disableSelection" call on an element.