# jQuery UI sortable & contenteditable=true not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, contenteditable

I am creating a list & want to make its item sortable and editable. So i am doing it like this:

```
<ul id="ul_list">
<li><span contenteditable="true">A</span></li>
<li><span contenteditable="true">B</span></li>
<li><span contenteditable="true">C</span></li>
</ul>

$("#ul_list").sortable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jzVa/

But if i use jquery ui sortable then my list item is losing focus for editing and that's why i am not able to edit them.

So please suggest how can i do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995329/if-i-do-jquery-sortable-on-a-contenteditable-items-i-then-cant-focus-mouse
gives a good solution~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i did it like this;

1. On mousedown event i applied the sortable()  so that user can sort elements by dragging them,
2. On click i destroyed the sortable .sortable("destroy"). So now the elements are editable.

Comment: @afro360 ok i will check my repository & will post the code here..it is a old code so i need to find out.

Answer (score 4):

We could make use of the cancel option provided by jquery sortable

```js
$("#ul_list").sortable({cancel: 'span'});
```

```css
#ul_list li{
    border:1px solid red;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul_list">
<li><span contenteditable="true">A</span></li>
<li><span contenteditable="true">B</span></li>
<li><span contenteditable="true">C</span></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on the text will make it editable. Can be sorted by clicking anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem and I fixed by the following code:

```
$('#ul_list').on("mousedown",function(){
    $("#ul_list").sortable();
});
```