# jQuery UI sortable & contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, contenteditable

I am using jquery sortable and contenteditable the problem is when I am using jquery sortable the contenteditable is not working so I have searched on stackoverflow I have got the solution but when I implemented it now the problem is on mousedown event the sortable is not working.

What am I doing worng.

[Here is the stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060003/jquery-ui-sortable-contenteditable-true-not-working-together?rq=1)

```
<div class="sortable">
  <div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;">
    <p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p>  </div>
    <div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;">
    <p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p>  </div>
    <div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;">
    <p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p>  </div>
</div>
```

First I am using this code

```
$('.sortable').sortable();
```

Second I am using this code

```
$('.sortable').on('onmousedown', function() {
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            cursor: 'move'
        });
    })
```

Comment: change onmousedown to mousedown.`$('.sortable').on('mousedown', function() {
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            cursor: 'move'
        });
    })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `onmousedown` to `mousedown`

```
$('.sortable').on('mousedown', function() {
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        cursor: 'move'
    });
})
```

Also on the click event of p destroy the sortable

```
 $('p').on('click', function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable( "destroy" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fum9sf2m/

Comment: It is  very hard to destroy it. I mean I have to click twice to destroy sortable and twice click to regain sortable can it be little smootly

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('mouseup','.sortable',function(){
     $( ".sortable" ).sortable( "destroy" );
}
```